# Arduino DUE Bossac Lockup after Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: arduino-due, ubuntu, bossa

I already asked my question in the Arduino Forum here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=353846.0 but got no answer so far. Thus I hope here might be people who have a hint for me.

Since I introduced some Ubuntu patches I suspect these patches are to blame. But frankly I have no clue.

Here is what I got:

If I connect the programming port then Arduino IDE 1.6.5 properly recognizes it as the programming port. Thus I assume that the cable is properly plugged in and the Arduino powered. In addition I get

```
> lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 019: ID 2341:003d Arduino SA
...

> dmesg
...
 2074.703747] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 18
[ 2076.678150] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 2076.696405] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=003d
[ 2076.696407] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[ 2076.696409] usb 3-3: Product: Arduino Due Prog. Port
[ 2076.696409] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[ 2076.696410] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 55437333537351F0F1D0
[ 2076.696501] usb 3-3: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[ 2076.697270] cdc_acm 3-3:1.0: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
...
```

So I assume the device is definitely connected.

```
> ls -l /dev/ttyACM3
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 3 Okt 17 09:56 /dev/ttyACM3


> grep dialout /etc/group
dialout:x:20:udo
```

So I assume that my user "udo" is authorized to access the device. Everything as it should be and as it used to be.

The patches that were applied are:

```
> grep "2015-10-16.* upgrade " /var/log/dpkg.log
2015-10-16 09:25:29 upgrade udev:amd64 204-5ubuntu20.14 204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:30 upgrade libudev1:amd64 204-5ubuntu20.14 204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:31 upgrade libpam-systemd:amd64 204-5ubuntu20.14 204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:32 upgrade systemd-services:amd64 204-5ubuntu20.14 204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:32 upgrade libsystemd-daemon0:amd64 204-5ubuntu20.14 204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:33 upgrade libsystemd-login0:amd64 204-5ubuntu20.14 204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:34 upgrade chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1097 45.0.2454.101-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1099
2015-10-16 09:25:35 upgrade libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.1 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.2
2015-10-16 09:25:35 upgrade libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:all 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.1 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.2
2015-10-16 09:25:36 upgrade google-chrome-stable:amd64 45.0.2454.101-1 46.0.2490.71-1
2015-10-16 09:25:41 upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:42 upgrade libgbm1:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:43 upgrade libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:43 upgrade mesa-common-dev:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:44 upgrade libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:45 upgrade libgles2-mesa:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:45 upgrade libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:46 upgrade libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:47 upgrade libglapi-mesa:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:48 upgrade libopenvg1-mesa:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:48 upgrade libegl1-mesa:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:49 upgrade libgudev-1.0-0:amd64 1:204-5ubuntu20.14 1:204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:50 upgrade libhunspell-1.3-0:amd64 1.3.2-6ubuntu2 1.3.2-6ubuntu2.1
2015-10-16 09:25:51 upgrade libspice-server1:amd64 0.12.4-0nocelt2ubuntu1.1 0.12.4-0nocelt2ubuntu1.2
2015-10-16 09:25:51 upgrade libxatracker2:amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5
2015-10-16 09:25:52 upgrade linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic:amd64 3.13.0-65.105 3.13.0-65.106
2015-10-16 09:25:55 upgrade libsystemd-journal0:amd64 204-5ubuntu20.14 204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:25:55 upgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:0.220.7 1:0.220.8
2015-10-16 09:25:56 upgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:0.220.7 1:0.220.8
2015-10-16 09:25:57 upgrade python3-distupgrade:all 1:0.220.7 1:0.220.8
2015-10-16 09:25:58 upgrade update-manager:all 1:0.196.13 1:0.196.14
2015-10-16 09:25:59 upgrade update-manager-core:all 1:0.196.13 1:0.196.14
2015-10-16 09:26:00 upgrade python3-update-manager:all 1:0.196.13 1:0.196.14
2015-10-16 09:26:01 upgrade firefox:amd64 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 41.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:04 upgrade firefox-locale-en:amd64 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 41.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:05 upgrade flashplugin-installer:amd64 11.2.202.521ubuntu0.14.04.1 11.2.202.535ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:06 upgrade gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.1 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.2
2015-10-16 09:26:06 upgrade gir1.2-gudev-1.0:amd64 1:204-5ubuntu20.14 1:204-5ubuntu20.15
2015-10-16 09:26:07 upgrade linux-headers-3.13.0-65:all 3.13.0-65.105 3.13.0-65.106
2015-10-16 09:26:12 upgrade linux-headers-3.13.0-65-generic:amd64 3.13.0-65.105 3.13.0-65.106
2015-10-16 09:26:15 upgrade linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic:amd64 3.13.0-65.105 3.13.0-65.106
2015-10-16 09:26:21 upgrade linux-libc-dev:amd64 3.13.0-65.105 3.13.0-65.106
2015-10-16 09:26:22 upgrade thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 1:38.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 1:38.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:23 upgrade thunderbird:amd64 1:38.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 1:38.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:26 upgrade thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 1:38.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 1:38.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:27 upgrade thunderbird-locale-en-us:all 1:38.2.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 1:38.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:27 upgrade liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.9.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:29 upgrade liboxideqtquick0:amd64 1.9.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:30 upgrade liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.9.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:33 upgrade oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.9.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2015-10-16 09:26:33 upgrade python-tz:all 2012c-1build1 2012c-1ubuntu0.1
```

I checked with Arduino 1.6.0 (which worked till yesterday) and then installed Arduino 1.6.5. Arduino 1.6.5 also fails to upload but definitely recognizes the port. What I get though is the message "Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/ttyACM3..." and then the upload is stuck. To be more precise bossac gets stuck and puts 100% load on one of my cores.

I also installed bossash. If I issue a "scan" command bossash will properly detect the correct port. However I will also lockup with 100% load on one of the cores. So the issue is probably not related to the IDE at all but to bossa.

Has anyone a hint how I might fix this? That is why bossac lock up and how to get it to upload again as it did before?